# How to fix mongo db query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a request for statistics from the db. Here's the code:

```
Stats.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                'advertiser': '$advertiser',
                'offer': '$offer'
            },
            stats: {
                $push: {
                    'date': '$date',
                    'spent': '$spent',
                    'revenue': '$revenue'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id.advertiser',
            offers: {
                $push: {
                    _id: '$_id.offer',
                    stats: '$stats'
                }
            }
        }
    }], callback);
```

I want that the advertiser had all his offers, and inside the offers there was statistics on the days along with spent and revenue. The problem is that statistics by day can be more than one and I get this answer:

```
stats   […]
0   {…}
date    2018-01-30T22:00:00.000Z
spent   100
revenue 200
1   {…}
date    2018-01-30T22:00:00.000Z
spent   20
revenue 20
```

But, I need to have the same days folded into one and spent and revenue added
Also, I want to add offer info from offers collection into result offers, like I do with advertisers. Maybe someone know how to do this. Thank you

Stats in db:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5a4f873d381727000404d171"
},
"advertiser": {
    "$oid": "5a4f74619f0251000438fe4a"
},
"offer": {
    "$oid": "5a4f748c9f0251000438fe4b"
},
"spent": 415.19,
"revenue": 780.92,
"date": "2018-01-02T22:00:00.000Z",
"user": {
    "$oid": "5a4f74259f0251000438fe40"
},
"__v": 0
```

}

Stats Schema

```
const StatsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
advertiser: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Advertiser',
    required: true
},
offer: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Offer',
    required: true
},
spent: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
revenue: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
date: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
user: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
}});
```

Comment: Please add some sample documents from `Stats` collection so that it's easier for people to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first project the `day`, `month` and `year` then group accordingly as below. This is a relatively long query you could add in some optimisations based on your workflow.

```
db.createCollection('statistics');

db.statistics.insertMany([
    {advertiser: "1", offer: "1", date: "2018-01-30T22:00:00.000Z", spent: 10, revenue: 20},
    {advertiser: "1", offer: "1", date: "2018-01-30T21:00:00.000Z", spent: 20, revenue: 20},
    {advertiser: "2", offer: "2", date: "2018-01-30T22:00:00.000Z", spent: 10, revenue: 20},
    {advertiser: "2", offer: "2", date: "2018-01-30T21:00:00.000Z", spent: 1000, revenue: 2000},
    {advertiser: "2", offer: "2", date: "2018-01-31T22:00:00.000Z", spent: 25, revenue: 50}
])

transform_date = {
    $project: {
        advertiser: 1,
        offer: 1,
        date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: { $arrayElemAt: [ {$split: ["$date", "Z"]}, 0 ] }, timezone: 'UTC' } },
        spent: 1,
        revenue: 1      
    }
}

project_year_month_day = {
    $project: {
        advertiser: 1,
        offer: 1,
        date: 1,
        spent: 1,
        revenue: 1,
        year: { $year: "$date" },
        month: { $month: "$date" },
        day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" }
    }
}

group_by_date_advertiser_offer_and_sum = {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            advertiser: "$advertiser",
            offer: "$offer",
            day: "$day",
            month: "$month",
            year: "$year"
        },
        spent: { $sum: "$spent" },
        revenue: { $sum: "$revenue" },
        dates: { $push: "$date" }
    }
}

group_advertiser_offer_and_push = {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            advertiser: "$_id.advertiser",
            offer: "$_id.offer"
        },
        stats: {
            $push: {
                dates: "$dates",
                spent: "$spent",
                revenue: "$revenue"
            }
        }
    }
}

group_advertiser_and_push = {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.advertiser",
        offers: {
            $push: {
                _id: "$_id.offer",
                stats: "$stats"
            }
        }
    }
}

db.statistics.aggregate([
    transform_date, 
    project_year_month_day, 
    group_by_date_advertiser_offer_and_sum, 
    group_advertiser_offer_and_push, 
    group_advertiser_and_push
])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[{
    "_id": "2",
    "offers": [{
        "_id": "2",
        "stats": [{
            "dates": [ISODate("2018-01-31T22:00:00Z")],
            "spent": 25,
            "revenue": 50
        }, {
            "dates": [ISODate("2018-01-30T22:00:00Z"), ISODate("2018-01-30T21:00:00Z")],
            "spent": 1010,
            "revenue": 2020
        }]
    }]
} {
    "_id": "1",
    "offers": [{
        "_id": "1",
        "stats": [{
            "dates": [ISODate("2018-01-30T22:00:00Z"), ISODate("2018-01-30T21:00:00Z")],
            "spent": 30,
            "revenue": 40
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Is it big problem, if my date type of string? Can I convert in $project date like new Date('$date')

Comment: I updated the snippet, check if that can work for your use case. You can use `dateFromString` in project but to use that `Z` should not be present in the date string which is why I am using split("Z") and getting the first element for expected parsing.

Comment: OK. How I can push offer info from offer collection into offers in result?

Comment: You can try using `ref` using the QueryPopulation API in mongoose or a `$lookup` aggregation which could be pretty taxing.

Comment: Yes, I use $lookup to find offer in offer collection.
{
            $lookup: {
                from: 'offers',
                localField: 'offers._id',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'offers.offer'
            }
        }
But, if I use this I delete info inside offers and paste only offer info from offer collection. What I should write in '$lookup as'.

Comment: I fixed. Thank you for your time and help